# Alternative way to check for empty \rightmark; \ifstr won't do while using babel package

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

I’m trying to put my own pagestyle together by using the `scrlayer-scrpage` package.
That pagestyle should content a `\vrule` in the `\rohead`, that separates the sectionname from the sectionnumber for the case that the `\rightmark` isn’t “empty”.

To do so I’m using `\ifstr{\rightmark}{}{}{\vrule…}` which works as long I’m not using the babel package. But as babel is some kind of essential I need to use that, which brings me to my question:

Is there an alternative way to check for an “empty” `\rightmark`?

Or the other way around, how can I find out to what the “empty” `\rightmark` expands?

I tried `\ifx\rightmark\empty\relax\else do that \fi` without success.

In my example I used a `\fbox` to visualize that `\fbox{\rightmark}` seems to expand like `\fbox{}`.

**Example:**

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\automark*[section]{}


\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}% \rightmark without \thesection

\rohead{%
  \fbox{}% reference for empty fbox
  \fbox{\rightmark}%
  \hspace{2ex}%
  \makebox[3em][l]{%
    \ifstr{\rightmark}{}{}{%
      \vrule width 0.1ex height 2.5ex \hspace{2pt} \hfill \thesection}%
  }%
  \hspace{-3em}
}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{chapter}
  \lipsum[1-17]
  \section{section}
  \lipsum[18-25]
\end{document}
```

On page 3 the `\rohead` should be empty, (except for the two empty `\fbox`’es in that example) because the first section is on page 4. The screenshot shows the output if the `babel` package is used. Without the babel package it works as expected.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `\ifstr` doesn't conflict with `babel`. However, with `babel` `\ifstr{\rightmark}{}` is the same as `\ifstr{\protect\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{\protect\bbl@restore@actives ...}}{}` which always gives false regardless if `...` is empty or not

Comment: Ok it doesn’t conflict, but it somehow affects it. I edited the title.
What you mean is, that it can’t be done with \ifstr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can typeset the mark in a temporary box and measure it; this would fail if the mark only contains zero width boxes.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\automark*[section]{}


\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}% \rightmark without \thesection

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifemptymark}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \ifdim\wd\z@=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\rohead{%
  \fbox{}% reference for empty fbox
  \fbox{\rightmark}%
  \hspace{2ex}%
  \makebox[3em][l]{%
    \ifemptymark{\rightmark}{}{%
      \vrule width 0.1ex height 2.5ex \hspace{2pt} \hfill \thesection}%
  }%
  \hspace{-3em}%
}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{chapter}
  \lipsum[1-17]
  \section{section}
  \lipsum[18-25]
\end{document}
```

[image]